# Kops: Adjust existing kubernetes storageclass

Tags: kubernetes, kops

**Summary**

How do I adjust an existing storageclass or create a new storage class in Kops?

**Background**

We have a Kops provisioned cluster with the `gp2` storageclass set up. We require the `volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer` set so that pods requiring multiple volumes get them all in the same AZ; otherwise we get unschedulable pods because the underlying EBS volumes are in different availability zones.

Alternatively I can create a new storageclass manually with kubectl but the Kops docs are not clear on the process

Comment: Did you try to duplicate default storage class and add `Allowed Topologies` parameter as mention in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs)?  Parameters like `zone` and `zones` were deprecated. To confirm, you are using AWS, not GKE?

Comment: Indeed, we are using AWS. 

By "duplicate the default storage class" do you mean use kubectl to do it? I am trying to find a pure Kops way of doing this because I'd like to avoid an unmanaged storage class if possible. If have not found a way to tell Kops to make the storage class on my behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try to introduce your own, user defined K8S storage class as a form of cluster [addons](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kops/pkg/apis/kops#AddonSpec), that can be specified as a part of the Cluster resource's spec (kept in KOPS's cluster S3 bucket state), e.g:

```
spec:
  addons:
  - s3://kops-addons/sc-gp2-us-east-2.yaml
```

At least this form can be used when bootstraping KOPS cluster directly from manifest file according to the official doc [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/operations/addons.md).

To adhere your storage class to specific cloud compute zones please use 'allowedTopologies' as @PjoterS suggested.

Comment: Thanks, a cluster addon looks like the way to go. As for using "allowedTopologies": it's not that I need specific zones, rather, I just need the underling volumes to be in the same zone as the pod (whichever zone that ends up being) so I may not need to specifically spell out which zones when using `allowedTopologies`.